# What command to use to get the revision history of the files in a folder

Tags: shell, unix, history, prompt, revision

I am trying to get the revision history of files from my windows views of a project. I know that there is a command in Unix that I can give and it will provide the file-names in one column and associated revision dates in parallel column (or something similar). I can use unix view from my windows and also I have created the folders view of the src code directly from windows. Does anybody know what is that command? If so please help.

BR
Vard

Answer (score 2):

`ls -l` will give you modification times of the files, but Unix/Linux doesn't (by default) store revisions. For that you'll need some sort of SCM system (e.g. Git / SVN / CVS etc.)

[Clearcase](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/) (an SCM) provides a [filesystem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230196) that allows you to store revisions of the file natively. That may be another option. Versions appear in subdirectories corresponding to each file.

Comment: VMS also has native revisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain also what SCM system is?